# C++ bit string to int conversion

Tags: c++

I am trying to convert a bit string (bitString) of length 'sLength' to an int.
The following code works fine for me in my computer. Is there any case where it may not work?

```
int toInt(string bitString, int sLength){

    int tempInt;
    int num=0;
    for(int i=0; i<sLength; i++){
        tempInt=bitString[i]-'0';
        num=num+tempInt * pow(2,(sLength-1-i));
    }

    return num;
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: You should prefer to use `std::stoi` with `base=2`.

Comment: It will not work when the `bitString` contains more "bits" than `sizeof(int)*CHAR_BIT`.

Comment: @zch. Thanks for info on std::stoi. It will be really useful. I've been to conferences etc. on C++ 11, but the presenters have not mentioned it or only very briefly.

Comment: `bitString[i]-'0'` will work for both ASCII and the only other running code, EBCDIC. Note however: in EBCDIC `'S' - 'R'` is _not_ one. You might even do `bitString[i] & 1` which has the advantage yielding one bit: 0 or 1, even on erroneous data.

Comment: @zch why do I get this error? main.cpp:84:13: error: ‘stoi’ is not a member of ‘std’

Comment: @zch ,think I can't use 'stoi' in C++98!

Answer (score 5):

`pow` works with doubles. Result may be inaccurate. Use bit arithmetic instead

```
num |= (1 << (sLength-1-i)) * tempInt;
```

Don't also forget about cases when `bitString` contains symbols other than '0' and '1' or too long

Comment: Thanks. I have control over the contents of the bitString

Answer (score 3):

Or, you can let the standard library do the heavy lifting:

```
#include <bitset>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <climits>

// note the result is always unsigned
unsigned long toInt(std::string const &s) {
    static const std::size_t MaxSize = CHAR_BIT*sizeof(unsigned long);
    if (s.size() > MaxSize) return 0; // handle error or just truncate?

    std::bitset<MaxSize> bits;
    std::istringstream is(s);
    is >> bits;
    return bits.to_ulong();
}
```

Comment: +1 my first thought was: doesn't `std::bitset` provide this? And the bitset size can be `constexpr` ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Why not change your for loop to the more efficient and far more simple C++11 version:

```
for (char c : bitString)
  num = (num << 1) |  // Shift the current set of bits to the left one bit
        (c - '0');    // Add in the current bit via a bitwise-or
```

By the way, you should also check that the number of bits specified does not overrun an `int` and you may want to make sure that each char in the string is either a `'0'` or `'1'`.

Comment: You don't need `i` and you don't need `bitString` in the body of the loop, when you have `c` the character you are currently working with.

Comment: @Goldshteyn error: range-based ‘for’ loops are not allowed in C++98 mode

Comment: also,I may not use the whole string, but only 'sLength' part of it

Answer (score 2):

Answer and notice about inaccuracy of floating-point numbers already given; here's a more readable implementation with integer arithmetic, though:

```
int toInt(const std::string &s)
{
    int n = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < s.size(); i++) {
        n <<= 1;
        n |= s[i] - '0';
    }

    return n;
}
```

Notes:

1. You don't need an explicit length. That's why we have `std::string::length()`.
2. Counting from zero results in cleaner code, because you don't have to do the subtraction every time.

Comment: I some times read only a part of string, thats why explicit length

Answer (score 0):

I see directly three cases where it may not work :

- `pow` Works with `double`, your result may be inaccurate, you can fix it with :

  ```
  num |= tempInt * ( 1 << ( sLength - 1 - i ) );
  ```
- If `bitString[i]` is not a '0' or '1',
- If your number in the string in bigger than the `int` limit.

---

If you have control over the last two points, your resulting code could be :

```
int toInt( const string& bitString )
{
    int num = 0;

    for ( char c : bitString )
    {
        num <<= 1;
        num |= ( c - '0' );
    }

    return num;
}
```

Don't forget the `const reference` as a parameter.

Comment: thanks.I have control over the last two points. May be I will go by Goldshteyn's method.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (std::string::reverse_iterator it = bitString.rbegin();
    it != bitString.rend(); ++it) {
    num *= 2;
    num += *it == '1' ? 1 : 0;
}
```